# Can't save custom collection user setting

Tags: c#, .net

I am new to C# and .Net, coming from a world of C++. I am learning C# WPF by creating a little application for myself.

Currently I need to create a collection user setting. Cause after that I want to be able to bind this collection to a list box, I decided to use ObservableCollection.

So far after quite a long searching here is what I have:

```
public class ProfileStorage : ApplicationSettingsBase
  {
    public ProfileStorage()
    {
      this.UserProfiles = new ObservableCollection<UserProfile>();
    }

    [UserScopedSetting()]
    [SettingsSerializeAs(System.Configuration.SettingsSerializeAs.Binary)]
    [DefaultSettingValue("")]
    public ObservableCollection<UserProfile> UserProfiles
    {
      get
      {
        return (ObservableCollection<UserProfile>)this["UserProfiles"];
      }
      set
      {
        this["UserProfiles"] = value;
      }
    }
  }

  [Serializable]
  public class UserProfile
  {
    public String Name { get; set; }
  }
```

I was even able to browse it in settings designer and create a setting named "ProfileStorage". Here is the code created automatically in settings.designer.cs:

```
        [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        public global::tick_time.ProfileStorage ProfileStorage {
            get {
                return ((global::tick_time.ProfileStorage)(this["ProfileStorage"]));
            }
            set {
                this["ProfileStorage"] = value;
            }
        }
```

The problem is that I can't save this setting! I used following code to check that.

```
if (null == Properties.Settings.Default.ProfileStorage)
  {
    Properties.Settings.Default.ProfileStorage = new ProfileStorage()
      {
        UserProfiles = new ObservableCollection<UserProfile>
          {
            new UserProfile{Name = "1"},
            new UserProfile{Name = "2"}
          }
      };
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
  }
}
```

ProfileStorage is always Null.

So here is my problem. After some searching I've found following hack described in one post on Stackowerflow. I need to change manually settings.Designer.cs:

```
    [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    public ObservableCollection<UserProfile> Profiles
    {
      get
      {
        return ((ObservableCollection<UserProfile>)(this["Profiles"]));
      }
      set
      {
        this["Profiles"] = value;
      }
    }
```

This way setting "Profiles" can be properly saved and restored.

But I don't like this solution cause:

1. It's a hack
2. settings.designer.cs is changed every time you add/remove setting
3. well, again, it's a hack!

So I guess the problem is somewhere in serializing. But ObservableCollection can be perfectly serialized, as we can see in example.

P.S. I also have tried to browse for `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<tick_time.UserProfile>` in settings Designer (tick_time is the name of my project namespace), but I haven't had any luck with it.

So, I will appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more searching I was able to come up with less hacking solution.
I used the idea from http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/6f0a2b13-88a9-4fd8-b0fe-874944321e4a/ (see the last comment).

The idea is to modify not the settings.Designer.cs, but the specifically created another file. Automatically generated `Settings` is partial, so we can finish it's definition in other file. So I just made dedicated file to contain manually added properties!

And it actually worked.

So for now I will treat it as an answer.